# How to say "by ___"

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

How do I say an action was performed "by" someone?

For example:

> I was rejected *by* him.
>
> I was laughed at *by* him

Sorry if I'm not making sense.. basically when someone else does something to another person.

Answer (score 10):

"に" coupled with the [passive form](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/causepass) of a verb will do the trick.

> I was rejected by him
>
> 彼に断られた
>
> I was laughed at by him
>
> 彼に笑われた

In the above examples, the English "by" would correspond to the "に".

---

The passive form can also be combined with the causative form, to form a causative-passive form.

> He made me laugh
>
> 彼に笑わせられた